# Problem with connecting socket io when deploying app with Render

Tags: reactjs, node.js, express, socket.io

So everything worked well on localhost but when deploying app it just wont connect to socket.io but everything else works fine.
Hopefully someone can tell whats the problem? :((

Client side:

```
function App() {
  const user = useSelector((state) => state.user);
  const mode = useSelector((state) => state.mode);
  const theme = useMemo(() => createTheme(themeSettings(mode)), [mode]);
  const isAuth = Boolean(useSelector((state) => state.token));

  const socket = useRef();
  const [onlineUsers, setOnlineUsers] = useState([]);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();


  useEffect(() => {
      if (!socket.current && isAuth) {
          socket.current = io("https://socialize-0746.onrender.com", {transports: ['websocket']});
          socket.current.emit('addUser', user._id);
```

server side:

```
import { Server } from 'socket.io';
import http from 'http';
import express from "express";

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = new Server(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: 'wss://socialize-0746.onrender.com/',
    methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
    credentials: 'true'
  }
});


//When connect
io.on('connect', (socket) => {
    console.log(`a user connected: ${socket.id}`)
    socket.on('addUser', userId=>{
      addUser(userId, socket.id);
      io.emit('getUsers', users);
    });

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 6001;
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL)
.then(() => {
    app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on Port: ${PORT}`));
  }).catch((error) => console.log(`${error} did not connect`));
```

There is of course alot going on server side but i did only post lines of code related to this problem. I think problem is somewhere initializing socket on server side and/or calling it from client.

when i open devtools on chrome it gives:

index-m2ixEBle.js:171 WebSocket connection to 'wss://socialize-0746.onrender.com/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket' failed:

deployed app is running on https.

I have tried pretty much everything you can google but nothing seems to work!